# Rate constant and Michaelis Menten

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry, enzymes

Please consider the following figure of a concentration over time (msec) diagram with variables for an enzyme, a substrate bound enzyme and a product.

[image]

Recall that $\ce{E + S \leftrightharpoons ES \rightharpoonup E + P}$ and also recall that the velocity constant of the respective reactions are noted $k_1 , k_2, k_3$.

What I would like to know is:

On the plot provided, is the slope of $[ES]$ equal to $k_2$ and is the slope of $[E]$ equal to $k_1 + k_3$ thereby giving some insight/explanation for $k_m$ which is used to determine the *affinity* of an enzyme?

Any more details on Michaelis Menten is greatly appreciated but please note that my level of understanding is limited on the topic.

Comment: The data in the graph are not really corresponding to the chemical equation.  Assuming the data for [E] and [ES] are correct, [P] vs t should have increasing slope (be a concave-up curve, nearly-parabolic because [ES] vs t is nearly linear) until [ES] reaches a constant value around 2msek, beyond which point [P] vs t should be linear with a substantially positive slope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\ce{E + S <=>ES -> E + P}$

$\frac{d[\ce{ES}]}{dt}=-\frac{d[\ce{E}]}{dt}=  k_1[\ce{E}][\ce{S}]-k_2[\ce{ES}] -k_3[\ce{ES}]  $

> is the slope of $[ES]$ equal to $k_2$ ?

no

> is the slope of $[E]$ equal to $k_1 + k_3$

no

Answer (score 0):

> On the plot provided, is the slope of [ES] equal to k2 and is the
>   slope of [E] equal to k1+k3 thereby giving some insight/explanation
>   for km which is used to determine the affinity of an enzyme?

As DavePhD said, no to both counts.  First note that in your system, $\ce{E_0=E +ES}$, where $\ce{E_0}$ is the total amount of enzyme added, and $\ce{E_0}$ is conserved -- enzymes, as catalysts, are created or destroyed in the reaction.  This means $\frac{d\ce{E_0}}{dt}=0$, which implies that $\frac{d\ce{E}}{dt}=-\frac{d\ce{ES}}{dt}$.  So the slope of [ES] is negative the slope of [E].

Second, as you study more about Michaelis Menten kinetics, you will come to appreciate that this data is (mostly) for the *un*steady-state regime, also often called the *pre*steady-state regime.